# How to create URLs from files that are not in the same folder as the class

Tags: java, audio

I want to create an `AudioClip` from a `URL` that represents a file. I know that if the audio file is in the same folder as the class, I can use `class_name.getResource(String filename)`, then use `Applet.newAudioClip()` to create an audio clip for the `URL`, but what is the file is in a different folder?

Comment: `new URL("file://" + pathToFile)`?

Comment: Is pathToFile a string or a File object? (Sorry if this sounds dumb.)

Answer (score 0):

If file is in your project's archive, you can use `ClassLoader` to get resource.
File should be in root dir of archive, or in META-INF dir

```
java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String name);
```

Comment: How can you specify the folder? Can you use a file object? Also is `java.lang` needed?

Comment: File - ./file.ext, /file.ext or file.ext

Comment: java.lang is package. No need